# C function (fgets) mitigation

Tags: c, fgets

I can't understand why taking the input using `fgets` always gives me "Wrong password" for my program.

However, when I use `gets()`, like   `gets(array);` it works.

Expected outputs: when the password is wrong, prints "Wrong Passwor" and for correct one, let me see my "access is granted":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n=15;
    char array[n];
    int pass = 0;

    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
         fgets(array, n, stdin);

    if(strncmp(array, "password",n))
    {
        printf ("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }
    if(pass)
    {
       /* Now Give root or admin rights to user*/
        printf ("\n Root privileges given to the user \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you would have used a debugger to inspect what was read, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is, `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing newline, check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for `fgets()`.

> *`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.** [...]*

You need to remove that trailing newline before the comparison.

You can sanitize the input, using

```
 array[strcspn(array, "\n")] = 0;
```

to remove the trailing newline from the input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I really appreciate that!