# strlen problems, returns the right length + 2

Tags: c, strlen

I have a weird bug.

I wrote a function that gets a file and returns the length of each line:

```
void readFile1(char *argv[], int fileNumber,
          char *array_of_lines[NUMBER_OF_LINES+1], int *currNumOfLines)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[fileNumber], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, MSG_ERROR_OPEN_FILE, argv[fileNumber]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        printf("\n line contains : %s size is : %lu\n",line,strlen(line));
    }
}
```

The function always prints the **right number + 2**,
For example if file.txt contains only one line with `"AAAAA"` the function would print that the length is `7` instead of `5`,

```
 line contains : AAAAA
 size is : 7
```

Does someone know where is the bug?

Comment: Can you check this one: [C function (fgets) mitigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53262730/2173917)

Comment: The 7 is right there. You have WindowsLinefeed I assume. So your line `AAAAA` is technically `AAAAA\r\n`

Comment: Change `"\n line contains : %s size is : %lu\n"` to `"\n line contains : <%s> size is : %lu\n"` and run the program again. Things will become clearer.

Comment: What is the "right number" exactly? The number of printable characters?

Comment: What is your platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget that [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) leaves the newline in the buffer.

It seems you're reading a file created in Windows (where a newline is the *two* characters `"\r\n"`) on a system where newline is only `"\n"`. Those two characters are also part of the string and will be counted by `strlen`.

---

The reason I'm guessing you're reading a Windows-created file in a non-Windows system is because for files open in text-mode (the default) then the functions reading and writing strings will *translate* newlines from and to the operating-system dependent format.

For example on Windows, when writing plain `"\n"` it will be translated and actually written as `"\r\n"`. When reading the opposite translation happens (`"\r\n"` becomes `"\n"`).

On a system with plain `"\n"` line endings (like Linux or macOS), no translation is needed, and the `"\r"` part will be treated as any other character.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\n line contains : %s size is : %lu\n",line,strlen(line));
```

Here's a giveaway

Obtained output

```
 line contains : AAAAA
size is : 7
```

Expected output

```
 line contains : AAAAA size is : 7
```